# C# Not able to come out of the foreach loop after its completion

Tags: c#

After the completion of foreach loop, the for loop is suppose to be executed but its not happening .....the problem is after the
completion of foreach loop nothing
happens.. i need help, already wasted
my 2 days, i used break, return and
else ...but nothing helping me out,
break just break the loop after only
one iteration. nothing is helping me
out.

```
                        for (int i=0; i<=jArray.count; i++)
                        {//some code here  

                        Outlook.Application oOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
                        Outlook.NameSpace oNs = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                        Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = oNs.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
                        Outlook.Items inBoxItems = inBox.Items;
                        Outlook.MailItem newEmail = null;

                       inBoxItems = inBoxItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true");

                       foreach (object collectionItem in inBoxItems)
                       {
                           newEmail = collectionItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                           //MessageBox.Show(newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3));
                           if ( subject == newEmail.Subject)
                           {
                               MessageBox.Show(newEmail.Subject);
                               if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress & to == newEmail.To) & subject == newEmail.Subject)
                               {

                                   //*********************Case 1*************************

                                   if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                                   {
                                       //newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                       for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i2++)
                                       {
                                           progressBar2.Minimum = 0;
                                           progressBar2.Maximum = newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                           //string y = Convert.ToString(progressBar2.Maximum);
                                           //MessageBox.Show(y);
                                           progressBar2.Value = 1;
                                           progressBar2.Step = 1;
                                           newEmail.Attachments[i2].SaveAsFile(path + @"\" + newEmail.Attachments[i2].FileName);
                                           progressBar2.PerformStep();
                                       }
                                   }
                               }

                               else if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress & to == newEmail.To ) | subject == newEmail.Subject)
                               {

                                   if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                                   {
                                       //newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                       for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i2++)
                                       {
                                           progressBar2.Minimum = 0;
                                           progressBar2.Maximum = newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                           //string y = Convert.ToString(progressBar2.Maximum);
                                           //MessageBox.Show(y);
                                           progressBar2.Value = 1;
                                           progressBar2.Step = 1;
                                           newEmail.Attachments[i2].SaveAsFile(path + @"\" + newEmail.Attachments[i2].FileName);
                                           progressBar2.PerformStep();
                                       }
                                   }
                               }

                               else if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress | to == newEmail.To) & subject == newEmail.Subject)
                               {

                                   if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                                   {
                                       //newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                       for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i2++)
                                       {
                                           progressBar2.Minimum = 0;
                                           progressBar2.Maximum = newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                           //string y = Convert.ToString(progressBar2.Maximum);
                                           //MessageBox.Show(y);
                                           progressBar2.Value = 1;
                                           progressBar2.Step = 1;
                                           newEmail.Attachments[i2].SaveAsFile(path + @"\" + newEmail.Attachments[i2].FileName);
                                           progressBar2.PerformStep();
                                       }
                                   }
                               }

                               else if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress | to == newEmail.To) | subject == newEmail.Subject)
                               {


                                   if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                                   {
                                       //newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                       for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i2++)
                                       {
                                           progressBar2.Minimum = 0;
                                           progressBar2.Maximum = newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                           //string y = Convert.ToString(progressBar2.Maximum);
                                           //MessageBox.Show(y);
                                           progressBar2.Value = 1;
                                           progressBar2.Step = 1;
                                           newEmail.Attachments[i2].SaveAsFile(path + @"\" + newEmail.Attachments[i2].FileName);
                                           progressBar2.PerformStep();
                                       }
                                   }
                               }

                           }

                           else if (subject == newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3))
                           {
                               MessageBox.Show(newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3));
                               if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress & to == newEmail.To) & subject == newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3))
                               {


                                   if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                                   {
                                       //newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                       for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i2++)
                                       {
                                           progressBar2.Minimum = 0;
                                           progressBar2.Maximum = newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                           //string y = Convert.ToString(progressBar2.Maximum);
                                           //MessageBox.Show(y);
                                           progressBar2.Value = 1;
                                           progressBar2.Step = 1;
                                           newEmail.Attachments[i2].SaveAsFile(path + @"\" + newEmail.Attachments[i2].FileName);
                                           progressBar2.PerformStep();
                                       }
                                   }
                               }


                               else if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress & to == newEmail.To) | subject == newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3))
                               {


                                   if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                                   {
                                       //newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                       for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i2++)
                                       {
                                           progressBar2.Minimum = 0;
                                           progressBar2.Maximum = newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                           //string y = Convert.ToString(progressBar2.Maximum);
                                           //MessageBox.Show(y);
                                           progressBar2.Value = 1;
                                           progressBar2.Step = 1;
                                           newEmail.Attachments[i2].SaveAsFile(path + @"\" + newEmail.Attachments[i2].FileName);
                                           progressBar2.PerformStep();
                                       }
                                   }
                               }

                               else if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress | to == newEmail.To) & subject == newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3))
                               {


                                   if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                                   {
                                       //newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                       for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i2++)
                                       {
                                           progressBar2.Minimum = 0;
                                           progressBar2.Maximum = newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                           //string y = Convert.ToString(progressBar2.Maximum);
                                           //MessageBox.Show(y);
                                           progressBar2.Value = 1;
                                           progressBar2.Step = 1;
                                           newEmail.Attachments[i2].SaveAsFile(path + @"\" + newEmail.Attachments[i2].FileName);
                                           progressBar2.PerformStep();
                                       }
                                   }
                               }

                               else if ((to == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress | to == newEmail.To) | subject == newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3))
                               {


                                   if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0)
                                   {
                                       //newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                       for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i2++)
                                       {
                                           progressBar2.Minimum = 0;
                                           progressBar2.Maximum = newEmail.Attachments.Count;
                                           //string y = Convert.ToString(progressBar2.Maximum);
                                           //MessageBox.Show(y);
                                           progressBar2.Value = 1;
                                           progressBar2.Step = 1;
                                           newEmail.Attachments[i2].SaveAsFile(path + @"\" + newEmail.Attachments[i2].FileName);
                                           progressBar2.PerformStep();

                                       }
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                       }

                       reader.Close();
                       dataStream.Close();
                       response.Close();




                   }
```

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to me, the `foreach` is in the `for` so the `for` won't execute afterwards, do you mean the outer loop should continue?  Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: What have you tried till now ? Did you try putting Console Traces or stepping through with an attached debugger to know the reason why you're seeing this issue ? Also read about ExtractMethod and ComposeMethod - they'll help ; you have one huge function. Break it down...

Comment: Need more information about jArray?

Comment: First of all, split your branches to functions. I can't read code like this. Second of all do you expect us to read this much code?
A Testcase is shorter then 50 lines.

Comment: What's the value of jArray.count?

Comment: Yes it sounds like you expect the outer loop to continue, but the array has fewer elements in it than you think - debug and review the jArray length before you start.  Also, the <= Count looks suspect... perhaps on the last iteration its crashing with out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Some immediately obvious problems with the code:

1. You're using bitwise `and` and `or` operators instead of logical. Replace `&` with `&&` and `|` with `||`.
2. You close `reader`, `dataStream`, and `response` at the end of your for loop but never open them again. Actually, they're not used anywhere in the loop - what are they for?
3. Your original for loop looks like it should be iterating over the contents of jArray, but you don't use `jArray` or `i` anywhere in the loop. This means that you're saving the attachments for the same emails multiple times (assuming jArray contains more than one element).
4. As many people have mentioned, you iterate from 0 to jArray.Count inclusive which is probably 1 more iteration than you intended. Although it's not clear why you're iterating at all.

I've cleaned up the posted code a little bit for the sake of people's sanity:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= jArray.count; i++)
{
    Outlook.Application oOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.NameSpace oNs = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inBox = oNs.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    Outlook.Items inBoxItems = inBox.Items;
    Outlook.MailItem newEmail = null;

    inBoxItems = inBoxItems.Restrict("[Unread] = true");

    foreach (object collectionItem in inBoxItems)
    {
        newEmail = collectionItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        //MessageBox.Show(newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3)); 
        if (subject == newEmail.Subject)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(newEmail.Subject);
            if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress & to == newEmail.To) & subject == newEmail.Subject)
            {
                // save attachments
            }
            else if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress & to == newEmail.To) | subject == newEmail.Subject)
            {
                // save attachments
            }
            else if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress | to == newEmail.To) & subject == newEmail.Subject)
            {
                // save attachments
            }
            else if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress | to == newEmail.To) | subject == newEmail.Subject)
            {
                // save attachments
            }
        }
        else if (subject == newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3));
            if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress & to == newEmail.To) & subject == newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3))
            {
                // save attachments
            }
            else if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress & to == newEmail.To) | subject == newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3))
            {
                // save attachments
            }
            else if ((from == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress | to == newEmail.To) & subject == newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3))
            {
                // save attachments
            }
            else if ((to == newEmail.SenderEmailAddress | to == newEmail.To) | subject == newEmail.Subject.Remove(0, 3))
            {
                // save attachments
            }
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
}
```

Comment: +1 for a more thorough look at the code, I gave up when there was no response from the OP lol

Comment: Apologies for inconvenience... i am new to this....i will make my code more clear

Comment: jArray.Count will give the number of elements in JArray ...thats is coming after calling web services (Jason)..the result of jArray.Count is 7....the "i" is used in web serviecs which lies between for loop and foreach loop ...the problem is, i am not getting any error...the for loop is suppose to work after foreach, but it  doesn't

Comment: The foreach loop is within the for loop neither before or after.

i is not used except as a loop counter, presumably that's not what you intend?

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab.  Your outer loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<=jArray.count; i++)
```

Could possibly (read: almost certainly) cause an exception.  I would surmise that `count` is the total number of elements in the array and the array is 0-based.

The final iteration of the outer loop will cause an error - array out of bounds.  If the count is 5, your last indexable element is `jArray[4]`, but your loop will try to access `jArray[5]`.

Change it to this ( < instead of <= ):

```
for (int i=0; i < jArray.count; i++)
```

**Update:** based on NeilDurant's eagle eye, the inner code also has this (from first appearance) incorrect looping logic.  If this is the case, then on the first iteration into the `foreach` an error will occur.

Comment: Same thing later on with:
    for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i2++)
...which also incidentally looks wrong in that it's counting array indices from 1 to count, rather than 0 to count-1.

I would suggest using foreach if possible rather than index-based loops.

Comment: @NeilDurant good spot, I didn't bother looking at the inner code.  Looks like a VB port to me :-)